# How do I know if I can cut pressure sensors into different shapes?

Tags: pressure, sensors, consumer-electronics

I am building an imaging platform that requires the application of two pressure sensors shaped into a "hollow" semi-circle, pretty much C-shaped.

To do this, I thought of buying the following [sensors](https://store.technimeasure.co.uk/product/flexiforce-a401-force-sensor-25lbf-111n-range/), which can be [trimmed](https://www.tekscan.com/support/faqs/can-i-trim-flexiforce-sensor) into a desired shape.

These are relatively expensive and in the end I will have to buy more than two, so I was hoping to buy something more affordable, like this [second sensor](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/strain-gauges/1895556), **but I am not certain this can be cut into the C-shaped sensors I want.**

I have tried to contact the website company, but they said they will try to get back to me in some time, as this is a **I.E.E. product** and they are simply the distributors. I have tried to find the company **I.E.E.** online to no avail.

**Does anyone know if these pressure sensors can be cut?**

**Does anyone know where I can find the contact for the I.E.E company?**

Comment: Have you searched for IEE ?

Comment: I have, but the only thing I have found was many companies that sell their products, but the actual company doesn't seem to appear in my search engine.

Comment: If it's conductive foam with a membrane on opposite sides you can because it's homogenous, it's a strain gauge then you can't because there . You need to figure out what technology is being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the sensors described in your link are clearly described as strain gauges. They use a serpentine conductor pattern, as shown on the linked page, and you can not cut that conductor pattern and have a functional strain gauge. Furthermore, a strain gauge doesn't respond to **pressure** applied to it, it responds to **bending** in a direction perpendicular to the serpentine pattern. I don't think any strain gauge will do what you want.